# What is missing in my trigger?

Tags: t-sql, trigger, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have a table in which view names can be inserted and the following trigger should ensure that only vew_names can be inserted that really exist in the System (that's all the code the trigger consists of):

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_if_view_exists ON DATABASE FOR [INSERT], [UPDATE] 
AS 
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS(SELECT view_name from MySpecial_views EXCEPT SELECT name from sys.views)
       RAISERROR ('You can only insert views in that table that really exist!',10, 1) 
      ROLLBACK
   END -- end if 
END -- end trigger
```

However upon creation of the trigger I get the following errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure check_if_view_exists, Line 1
>   [Batch Start Line 0] Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure check_if_view_exists, Line 8 [Batch Start Line
>   0] Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

What is missing?
I have carefully read [the grammar of T-SQL Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) but can't figure out why my trigger is wrong.

Comment: I don't think you can create a database level trigger for DML instructions, only for DDL (create, alter, drop...). You will have to capture the insert or update for you table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** *As far as I am aware, you cannot create a database trigger as you are currently attempting to do...*

That being said, your 2 error messages, *"Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT'"* and *"Incorrect syntax near 'END'"*, are due to you using square brackets `[]` and missing a starting `BEGIN` respectively.

**Your Code (with comments):**

```
--Remove these Square Brackets...
CREATE TRIGGER check_if_view_exists ON DATABASE FOR [INSERT], [UPDATE] 
AS 
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS(SELECT view_name from MySpecial_views EXCEPT SELECT name from sys.views)
       -- You don't END an IF, you END a BEGIN
       RAISERROR ('You can only insert views in that table that really exist!',10, 1) 
      ROLLBACK
   END -- end if 
END -- end trigger
```

**Working Example:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MySpecialViews (
    ViewName varchar(10)
);
GO

-- Table or View, not on the Database
-- ...also no [] around INSERT and UPDATE
CREATE TRIGGER CheckIfViewExists ON dbo.MySpecialViews FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT ViewName FROM MySpecialViews EXCEPT SELECT name FROM sys.views)
    -- Added a BEGIN for the code after the IF
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('you can only insert views in that table that really exist!', 10, 1)
        ROLLBACK
    END
END;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MySpecialViews;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You Sir, are a genius! I applied your code above (however the part from CREATE TRIGGER until GO) and it works fine!

Comment: Nope, just experience. I've a long way to go before I even get counted as smart. Glad it works for you though, no go test it! :)

Comment: With "it works fine!" I of course already meant thath the trigger reacts correctly on wrongful insert attempts. ;-)